# Making container of overlapping content fit height of largest child

Tags: html, css

I'm building a carousel/slideshow-type widget that rotates between 3 quotes. Let's say the markup looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <blockquote>...</blockquote>
  <blockquote>...</blockquote>
  <blockquote>...</blockquote>
</div>
```

I want the three quotes to overlap in place, and I'll then transition their `opacity` property to create fade in/out transitions. My CSS looks something like this:

```
.carousel{
  position: relative;
}
.carousel blockquote{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Now if I leave it at this, the `.carousel` div will default to a `height` of `0px`, and will not push the rest of the page's content down.

So I need to specify a height, but the problem is each quote can be of different length, and as a result each `blockquote` can have a different heights.

So my question is this: how can I make sure that the `.carousel` div stretches to fit the `blockquote` with the biggest height?

I'd prefer a pure-CSS solution, but if it doesn't exist, an elegant JS or jQuery solution works for me as well.

Comment: could you not set height to auto? Also, could you possibly provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I believe you're going to have to use JavaScript to measure the rendered height of each child, and then assign that as the height of the carousel... but perhaps a CSS guru will have an alternative that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @MrCoder is the [default value for the height property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp), so I don't think that's going to help...

Comment: @Josh, I know that! however, OP obviously hasn't shown all code, and so something like that *should* work - but without further details/markup I can't see how they're running this 'carousel'

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own answer, using a simple jQuery loop to find out which blockquote is the tallest:

```
  var tallest = 0;
  $('blockquote').each(function (i, e){
    var h = $(e).height();
    tallest =  h > tallest ? h : tallest;
  });
  $('.carousel').height(tallest);
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it *is* possible without JavaScript! All props to Hugo Giraudel for finding the solution:

http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/d6006e5bb32f13d50d1ab07d6cadbc8f?editors=010

The trick is `float`ing all blockquotes and giving them a `width` of 100%. Hugo was then able to use `margin-left: -100%;` instead of `position: absolute` and `top: 0px` to overlap them, which doesn't disrupt the normal flow of the layout.

Note that the JS code in there is only used to animate each blockquote's opacity (which could also be done in CSS, but that's another problem), not to set the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you could eventually do is trying to center every blockquote vertically so that whatever their size is, and even if they overflow the container height, they remain centered anyway ?

Using that method maybe : http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

Classic problem and unsolvable without javascript.

If you want to do it without javascript I guess you could use a dirty hack like this: (if you know the width at least...)

```
<style>

    .carousel{
      position: relative;
      border: solid 1px #000;
    }
    .carousel blockquote{
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .carousel blockquote.next{
        float: left;
        margin-left: -340px;
        width: 300px;
    }

</style>

<div class="carousel">
    <blockquote>...</blockquote>
    <blockquote class="next">...<br>second</blockquote>
    <blockquote class="next">...<br>...<br>third</blockquote>
</div>
```